# Least Common Denominator, TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer,

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the given list of denominators, find the least common denominator by finding their LCM.

Example

For denominators = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], the output should be
solution(denominators) = 60.

This is my code:

```
from math import gcd

def solution(denominators):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x * y / gcd(x,y), denominators)
```

But then it says: TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Any suggestions, how to fix it?

Comment: Use `//` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to import `functools` as follows:

```
from math import gcd
import functools
def solution(denominators):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x * y / gcd(x,y), denominators)
```

Then let's try list `test_list = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, it returns:

```
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

The problem is that in the `/` you are creating a float as a result. `/` always returns a float. The solution for this is to use the int division operator `//`. `//` returns an integer. For example:

```
a = 1
b = 2
int_div  = a // b
print(int_div)
```

returns `0`.

Therefore the solution is to use:

```
functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x * y // gcd(x,y), denominators)
```